# ESLint plugin won't flag unsafe methods

Tags: security, javascript, plugins

I've installed ESLint along with a number of security plugins to attempt some javascript analysis, however when i feed it a small amount of vulnerable javascript, i get no output.

I installed ESLint with the following:

```
npm i -g eslint eslint-plugin-standard eslint-plugin-import \
eslint-plugin-node eslint-plugin-promise eslint-config-standard \
eslint-config-semistandard
npm i -g eslint-plugin-scanjs-rules
npm i -g eslint-plugin-angularjs-security-rules
npm i -g eslint-plugin-react
npm i -g eslint-plugin-security
npm i -g eslint-plugin-no-wildcard-postmessage
npm i -g eslint-plugin-no-unsanitized
npm i -g eslint-plugin-vue
npm i -g eslint-plugin-prototype-pollution-security-rules
```

Then i ran init on both:

```
npm init 
eslint --init
? How would you like to use ESLint? To check syntax and find problems
? What type of modules does your project use? JavaScript modules (import/export)
? Which framework does your project use? None of these
? Where does your code run? (Press <space> to select, <a> to toggle all, <i> to invert selection)Browser
? What format do you want your config file to be in? JavaScript
[...]
Successfully created .eslintrc.js file in /js-analysis
```

I feed in the following vulnerable demo code:

```
$ cat demo.js
var input = ['value',window.location.search.substring(2)]
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = input.value;

var url = window.location.search.substring(1);
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "<a href='"+url+"'>About</a>";
```

The package looks like this:

```
$ cat package.json
{
  "name": "js-analysis",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "demo.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

But then this command(which the plugin says should flag vulnerable unnerHTML use) gives no output:

```
$ eslint --plugin no-unsanitized ./demo.js
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure why the --plugin option didn't work, however the workaround I found was to add the following to the .eslintrc.js file created after running 'eslint --init'.

By adding the plugins and their rules manually like so:

```
cat .eslintrc.js
module.exports = {
  "env" : {
    "browser" : true,
    "es6" : true /** all es6 features except modules */
  },
  "plugins" : [
    "scanjs-rules",
    "no-unsanitized",
    "prototype-pollution-security-rules"
  ],
  "rules" : {
    /** useful rules from eslint **/

    /** ScanJS rules **/
    "scanjs-rules/accidental_assignment": 1,
    "scanjs-rules/assign_to_hostname" : 1,
    "scanjs-rules/assign_to_href" : 1,
    "scanjs-rules/assign_to_location" : 1,
    "scanjs-rules/assign_to_onmessage" : 1,
    "scanjs-rules/assign_to_pathname" : 1,
    "scanjs-rules/assign_to_protocol" : 1,
    "scanjs-rules/assign_to_search" : 1,
    "scanjs-rules/assign_to_src" : 1,
    "scanjs-rules/call_Function" : 1,
    "scanjs-rules/call_addEventListener" : 1,
    "scanjs-rules/call_addEventListener_deviceproximity" : 1,
    "scanjs-rules/call_addEventListener_message" : 1,
    "scanjs-rules/call_connect" : 1,
    "scanjs-rules/call_eval" : 1,
    "scanjs-rules/call_execScript" : 1,
    "scanjs-rules/call_hide" : 1,
    "scanjs-rules/call_open_remote=true" : 1,
    "scanjs-rules/call_parseFromString" : 1,
    "scanjs-rules/call_setImmediate" : 1,
    "scanjs-rules/call_setInterval" : 1,
    "scanjs-rules/call_setTimeout" : 1,
    "scanjs-rules/identifier_indexedDB" : 1,
    "scanjs-rules/identifier_localStorage" : 1,
    "scanjs-rules/identifier_sessionStorage" : 1,
    "scanjs-rules/new_Function" : 1,
    "scanjs-rules/property_addIdleObserver" : 1,
    "scanjs-rules/property_createContextualFragment" : 1,
    "scanjs-rules/property_crypto": 1,
    "scanjs-rules/property_geolocation" : 1,
    "scanjs-rules/property_getUserMedia" : 1,
    "scanjs-rules/property_indexedDB" : 1,
    "scanjs-rules/property_localStorage" : 1,
    "scanjs-rules/property_mgmt" : 1,
    "scanjs-rules/property_sessionStorage" : 1,

    /** no-unsanitized rules**/
    "no-unsanitized/method": "error",
    "no-unsanitized/property": "error",

    /** prototype-pollution-security-rules rules**/
    "prototype-pollution-security-rules/detect-merge": 1,
    "prototype-pollution-security-rules/detect-merge-objects": 1,
    "prototype-pollution-security-rules/detect-merge-options": 1,
    "prototype-pollution-security-rules/detect-deep-extend": 1
  }
};
```

It was possible to run combined plugins like:

```
$ eslint vulnerable-javascript.js
```